# ContentProvider shutdown warning even though implemented

Tags: android, warnings, android-contentprovider

I have done my own ContentProvider and overriden shutdown() method.
Why do I get this warning still:

W/ContentProvider﹕ implement ContentProvider shutdown() to make sure all database connections are gracefully shutdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log message is coming from the super class's implementation ([see source code)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/ContentProvider.java):

```
public void shutdown() {
    Log.w(TAG, "implement ContentProvider shutdown() to make sure all database " +
            "connections are gracefully shutdown");
}
```

Just don't call super.shutdown() in your own implementation and the log message should be gone.